# need notification on uninstallation of an application in android

Tags: android

Folks,

I have one application to develop in which I need notification when the user uninstalls   the application. I have ACTION_PACKGE_REMOVED action in Broadcast Receiver but it does nothing.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED))
        {
        System.out.println("Your Package Is removed By Your Child");
        System.out.println("Your Package Is removed By Your Child");
        System.out.println("Your Package Is removed By Your Child");
        System.out.println("Your Package Is removed By Your Child");
        System.out.println("Your Package Is removed By Your Child");
        System.out.println("Your Package Is removed By Your Child");
        System.out.println("Your Package Is removed By Your Child");
        SendSms(context);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be kinda illogical to expect your application to receive a notification when it gets uninstalled, because "un-installation" implies removal of your application from disk, which starts with killing the application if its running.

Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED